# What if I wrote all dependency in common class in spring? will it lead to memory issue in real time live project?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

> First Approach

**ServiceA.java**

```
public class ServiceA{

@Autowired
private ClassOne classOne;

@Autowired
private ClassThree classThree;

public void mwthod1(){
classOne.getDetails();
}

}
```

**ServiceB.java**

```
public class ServiceB{

@Autowired
private Classfive classFive;

@Autowired
private ClassOne classOne;

public void mwthod1(){
classOne.getDetails();
}

}
```

Here above ServiceA and ServiceB both having dependency of ClassOne, hence @autowired ClassOne in them.
Suppose I have dependency of ClassOne in 50 service class then 
Instead of autowiring in all service classes can I autowired in one common class? like below

> Second Approach

**BeanContainer.java**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Component
public class BeanContainer {

@Autowired
private ClassOne classOne;

@Autowired
private ClassTwo classTwo;

@Autowired
private ClassThree classThree;

@Autowired
private ClassFour classFour;

@Autowired
private ClassFive classFive;

}
}
```

**ServiceA.java**

```
public class ServiceA{

@Autowired
private BeanContainer beanContainer;

public void mwthod1(){
beanContainer.getClassOne().getDetails();
}

}
```

**ServiceB.java**

```
public class ServiceB{

@Autowired
private BeanContainer beanContainer;

public void mwthod1(){
beanContainer.getClassOne().getDetails();
}

}
```

Here above I only need to autowire only one class that is BeanContainer, so it would be a good approach to design or not? what is the differe between first and second approach.

Comment: As a side note, Spring already has a "BeanContainer" in itself (`BeanFactory/ApplicationContext`), so writing one yourself would be useless (as well as horrible design I mentioned in my first comment).

Comment: That's what i want to figure out what will be the effect of this code to my project

Comment: The effect would be harmful. So don't do it.

Comment: ok thanks for response

Comment: It has nothing to do with memory, your idea of "let's autowire everything" is just stupid design. You autowire the things you need. If you're autowiring dozens of things into a single class, then you have a design flaw. One that's **not** solved by creating a useless proxy to all the beans you have. I recommend going through Spring tutorials to see how clean Spring code generally looks like.

Comment: Please don't do this. You just reinvented Service Locator anti-pattern. For more details on why this is bad idea please look at this excellent article by Miško Hevery from Google http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/18/breaking-the-law-of-demeter-is-like-looking-for-a-needle-in-the-haystack/ and also Guide to Writing Testable Code http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf